# Unable to setup Planet scale database project in WSL 2 (window subsystem for linux)

Tags: ssl, next.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, prisma, planetscale

I started a next js project using [create-t3-app](https://create.t3.gg/) and setup planetscale with [prisma](https://planetscale.com/docs/prisma/automatic-prisma-migrations). I then copied my database URL into .env and run `pnpm prisma studio`. However, I run into an error that states:

```
Message: Error in Prisma Client request: 


Invalid `prisma.example.count()` invocation:


Can't reach database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`.
```

I have added the parameters required for prisma connection strings as found [here](https://planetscale.com/docs/concepts/secure-connections#ca-root-configuration) but the problem remains.

Does anyone know how to fix this? And does anyone know how to use planetscale in WSL?